# Анимация на JS или CSS3?

Tags: javascript, css3, angularjs, css-animation

[Есть вот такая анимация, пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0wyo1jkp/2/)
С помощью

```
transform: rotate(Xdeg)
```

Поворачивается по оси квадрат.
В начале плавно появляется и плавно исчезает.

Но есть проблема, нужно регулировать скорость во время движения, то есть нужно что бы можно было эту плавно остановить.

Что должно получится:
Мы нажимаем на кнопку, скорость плавно уменьшается и примерно через 2 оборота все блоки останавливаются.

Ради изменение скорости переделывать всю анимацию c CSS на JS?
И будет ли она такая же плавная на JS и как лучше сделать?
Так же через

```
transform: rotate(Xdeg)
```

Или лучше высчитывать кординаты и писать их через:

```
left: Xpx;
top: Xpx;
```

Сайт где рассчитано это использовать написан с использованием фреймворка AngularJS.
Возможно для него есть какие-то библиотеки для реализации анимаций?

Comment: А как насчёт `transition-timing-function`?

Answer (score 1):

Решил сделать на JS, вот то что получилось:

[Вот тут код](http://jsfiddle.net/m7acz2o0/14/)

Так же через `transform`, но управление через JS, а не через анимацию CSS

Comment: Плавного исчезновения нет. И расстояние между точкой исчезновения и появления существенно меньше расстояния между соседмими квадратами.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в примере я это не реализовал(исчезновения), у меня есть версия, где это реализовано, главное что это можно легко реализовать, а не то что этого не сделано в примере.

Answer (score 0):

> Нажимаем кнопку и все блоки плавно замедляются и останавливаются, на CSS я так понимаю что это реализовать невозможно?

<s>Неправильно понимаешь. Измени время анимации всё должно само замедлиться.</s>

UPDATE: Я неправ, подумаю ещё.

```css
body { padding: .5em; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
label  { cursor: pointer; }

input[type=checkbox] { display: none; }
#slow:checked ~ label[for=slow], #rotate:checked ~ label[for=rotate] { background: silver; }
#slow:checked ~ div { transition-duration: 31.4s; }
#rotate:checked ~ div { transform: rotate(1turn); }

label {
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 3.14s linear, transition-duration 3.14s step-start;
  height: 50vmin;
  width: 50vmin;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox id=slow><label for=slow>Slow</label>
<input type=checkbox id=rotate><label for=rotate>Rotate</label>
<div></div>
```

Comment: А как же те блоки которые уже крутятся?  
И с помощью времени нельзя будет остановить.

Comment: @Mr_Epic, можно попробоавть прописать и удалить текущее состояние скриптом, тогда что-то пересчитается, но не так... Подумаю.

Comment: Хм.. пауза же... Если заменить на анимацию, то там есть возсожность поставить на паузу - может, пойти этим путём?

Comment: всё равно не получится плавно остановить, остановка будет резкой.

Comment: @Mr_Epic, http://jsfiddle.net/ne6wr9r0/ - остановка как раз плавно, неплавно происходит изменение скорости - вероятно, браузер пересчитывает всю анимацию и перепрыгивает на новое значение.

Comment: ,я может чего-то не понял, но я не вижу плавной остановки.  Мне нужно сделать именно так, что после нажатие кнопки блок не резко останавливался, а в течении допустим 2сек. уменьшал свою скорость вращения в течении этих 2сек. и получится что за 2сек он плавно остановится.

Comment: @Mr_Epic, так тогда надо timing-function менять.

Comment: @Mr_Epic, а ещё можно вращать контейнер.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30213/discussion-between-mr-epic-and-qwertiy).